# Why can't I use querySelector in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am using protractor. I understand that protractor has Jquery like syntax but I need something that can
create conditions, variables and loops based on DOM elements in some of my testing. I want to be able to use querySelector. Using just promises won't let me do the kind of testing I need to do.

When I run it, it says:

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
```

or

```
Failed: document is not defined
```

or

```
Failed: window is not defined
```

I've set up a test to test this issue. It runs off a random web page that I was looking at it. It selects the footer using protractor and then attempts it using querySelector. If I enter the querySelector portion in the console, it runs the code correctly. I've also tried variations of querySelector, using window.document; this also works in the browser but not in protractor.

```
describe("Test", function()
{
  it('This is a test to test protractor' , function()
  {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get("https://facebook.github.io/jest/");
    $("#footer").getAttribute("innerHTML").then( function(value)
    {
      console.log("inside value then");
      console.log(value);

    });

    var queryse = document.querySelector("#footer").innerHTML;
    // var queryse = browser.document.querySelector("#footer").innerHTML;
    // var queryse = window.document.querySelector("#footer").innerHTML;

    console.log('query selector');
    console.log(queryse);
  });

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you're running in Protractor test case doesn't really run in browser, in fact it's executed in `Node.js`. You should think of it as an API that will afterwards communicate with the browser through `WebDriver`. That means that you cannot use browser specific `JavaScript` API in the code. The `$` helper is just there to make the syntax easy and understandable without knowing anything about Selenium. That's why `document` and `window` are inaccessible for you. If you want to read more about that: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md

Comment: What if I need to locate elements of the DOM without promises?

Comment: It's not possible, that's how `WebDriver` works and there's nothing you can do with that, sorry

Answer (score 4):

@Nhor's answer is mostly correct in terms of the environments and why you cannot use `document` and `window` directly. However, for what it's worth, you can definitely find elements in the DOM through [executeScript](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript).  The only question is, why do you need to do this?

Any locator you can use in the DOM, you can use in Protractor (though the syntax might be different).  Here's an example, I used `innerHTML` because that's what you were trying in your case:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('element test', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    var el = browser.executeScript('return document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML');
    el.then(function (text) {
        console.log(text); // logs "Super Calculator"
    });
  });
});
```

Finally, it's important to note that this `el` is restricted to javascript functions from within that `executeScript` call.  It is not a version of Protractor's `ElementFinder`, you cannot perform actions like `getText()` on it (though it is still a Promise, so you need to call `.then()`).  You can do a console log on the `el` to see what's in that object.

Comment: If it is still a promise, what benefit does this have over regular ElementFinder?

Comment: @munchschair There is no benefit really, which is why I included in my answer "why do you need to do this?".  Any locator you can get with `querySelector`, you can get in Protractor from their methods.  Just wanted to let you know it's possible

Comment: It's usefull, for instances, to write names, states, ids on the `it()` string...